# Scaling Node.js: Using autoscaling groups with small virtual servers or cluster processes on VM with many vCPUs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, node-cluster

In learning about Node.js's cluster module I've been turning over the following architecture in my head: Balancing costs with performance, would it be more beneficial (i.e. cheapest but still scalable) to run your Node.js application in a cloud service's autoscaling group using small servers with one virtual CPU (say, AWS's t2.small EC2, 1 vCPU, 2gb memory) or use a larger server (say, an m5.xlarge 4 vCPU, 16gb memory), run  Node.js to cluster four child processes to use the 4 vCPUs, but still autoscale?

A possible trade-off is the time it takes AWS to deploy another small server to autoscale, but on a low-traffic app or utility app you'll have to take on the cost of running the larger server when usage is low. But if the time it takes to spin up another server to handle the load is nominal, does that negate the benefits of using the cluster module?

Specifically, my question is twofold: Are these two approaches feasible and, if so, is my presumption about the cluster module's usefulness in the small server approach correct?